# speakers stop working

Tags: sound

I have no clue what to do.I have tried every suggestion online regarding stopping and starting pulse audio; and it fails to work. My speakers worked, then they stopped. Then, one day, I heard speaking, and the speakers were working. NOw, they have stopped again. I also tried to use bluetooth, which works, but it stops working. The speakers do exist; and I don't know why they started working, and then stopped. I am completely at a loss.

Comment: Edit your question and describe what you've already tried.

Comment: Also provide details such as what OS & release you're using, Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stack choices; so providing that detail may also be helpful, but it reads like hardware issues to me so have you explored that (ie. booted a different OS and tried it *live*? though you've given so little detail it's all guesswork with us not even knowing basic details such as OS, release etc)\

Comment: Have you tried deleting your user's `~/.config/pulse directory` then logging out and logging back in?

Comment: Thanks for responding; I have Acer Aspire E15-575T and Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried using the pavucontrol, the pulseaudio, even some suggestions to edit files that I followed for directions. I replaced the speakers in the laptop. I continue to see that the audio is light so muted, but I have checked the function key, and it is not muted. I have checked all programs, they are not muted. I cannot get the speakers to work, using every single suggestion on about 10 different websites. Here is the output and info if someone can please help! Having no sound is just not working for me.